# ATmega 328P SMD version

Tags: arduino, avr, atmega, surface-mount

Currently I am using the normal ATmega328P chip with my barebone Arduino I have made. 
I am planning to switch it with an SMD version of ATmega328P, since it's smaller in size it will consume less current and will be more compact.

My question is, does anyone know how to burn a bootloader in the chip? And after bootloading it, how do I actually burn the code which I have written on Arduino IDE 1.5.6 r2?

Comment: It will note consume less current, the silicon dies (or dice?) inside are exactly the same for both versions.

Comment: There are ways to save energy using an AVR MCU. Using a smaller package is not one of them.

Comment: I've edited your question to correct grammar and improve clarity, next time try to put some care on that aspect and you'll get better reactions ;)

Answer (score 2):

This: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9825 plus AVRdude will do the trick.  Just make sure to design in the 2x3 ICSP header just like on the Arudino board.  There are also ways to load both the bootloader and firmware at the same time, such as using a utility called srec_cat to combine the hex files.

To write your user code, you can either use the ICSP cable directly and forget the bootloader, or you can design in a serial port or USB to serial converter (I highly recommend the FTDI chips, the driver support is excellent).  I would recommend designing in a serial port anyway for debugging.  It's also possible to bring out a TTL serial port on a set of pin headers and then use something like this: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9716 .

And you will only get board area savings with the smaller chip, the power consumption will be identical.  However, there are software techniques you can use to reduce power consumption, such as putting the chip into deep sleep and then waking it back up with the watchdog timer.  The watchdog timer has a dedicated RC oscillator, so you can turn of the core, the main oscillator, and all of the peripherals and just wait for the watchdog interrupt.

Comment: yes my bad power consumption would be same..anyways size reduction is my main concern...so for size reduction it would be great..anyways i have never actually worked with avr micrcontrollers seperately...i ve started off straight with arduino uno..so never worked ICSP header nor with FTDI chips....i probably have to learn all this before i purchase atmega 328p smd..

Comment: can anyone kindly suggest a basoc idea of how do i actually start all this..considering the fact that you guys are speaking to a beginner...who has never worked with avr microcontrollers seperately..thanks

Comment: @riju: Step 1 is to get something you can play with. There are lots of reference designs for AVR devices, e.g. Arduino or Sparkfun offerings. Figure out how to use the AVR, then worry about integrating it into your device.